# Shell script: Count number of files in a particular type extension in single folder

Tags: shell, sh, ls

I am new with shell script.
I need to save the number of files with particular extension(.properties) in a variable using shell script.

I have used

```
ls |grep .properties$ |wc -l
```

but this command prints the number of properties files in the folder. How can I assign this value in a variable.

I have tried

```
count=${ls |grep .properties$ |wc -l}
```

But it is showing error like:

```
./replicate.sh: line 57: ${ls |grep .properties$ |wc -l}: bad substitution
```

- What is this type of errors?
- Please anyone help me to save the number of particular files in a variable for future use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong brackets, it should be `$()` (command output substitution) rather than `${}` (variable substitution).

```
count=$(ls -1 | grep '\.properties$' | wc -l)
```

You'll also notice I've use `ls -1` to *force* one file per line in case your `ls` doesn't do this automatically for pipelines, and changed the pattern to match the `.` correctly.

You can also bypass the `grep` totally if you use something like:

```
count=$(ls -1 *.properties 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
```

Just watch out for "evil" filenames like those with embedded newlines for example, though my `ls` seems to handle these fine by replacing the newline with a `?` character - that's not necessarily a good idea for *doing* things with files but it works okay for counting them.

There are better tools to use if you have such beasts and you need the *actual* file name, but they're rare enough that you generally don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a loop with globbing:

```
count=0
for i in *.properties; do
    count=$((count+1))
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a shell that supports arrays, you can simply capture all such file names

```
files=( *.properties )
```

and then determine the number of array elements

```
count=${#files[@]}
```

(The above assumes `bash`; other shells may require slightly different syntax.)

Comment: It'd be `count=$#files` with `z`shell.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use `find` instead of parsing `ls`. Then, use the `var=$(command)` syntax to store the value.

```
var=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*\.properties" | wc -l)
```

Reference: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

---

To solve the problem appearing if any file name contains new lines, you can use what [chepner suggests in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740836/shell-script-count-number-of-files-in-a-particular-type-extension-in-single-fol/25752885#comment40269287_25740941):

```
var=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*\.properties" -exec 'echo 1' | wc -l)
```

so that for every match it will print not the name, but any random character (in this case, `1`) and then the amount of them will be counted to produce the correct output.

Comment: This fails for the same reason that `ls *.properties` would; filenames with newlines would occupy more than 1 line. You would at least need to use something like `-exec 'echo 1'` in place of the default `-print` to ensure a single line of output per file.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
count=`ls|grep .properties$ | wc -l`
echo $count
```

Comment: it is showing zero as result. But the actual result is 3. :(

Comment: It works for me. Are your sure you have files with this extension in the folder?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your assignment like this:

```
count=$(ls -q | grep -c '\.properties$')
```

or

```
count=$(ls -qA | grep -c '\.properties$')
```

if you want to include hidden files.
This works with all kind of filenames because we're using `ls` with `q`.
Sure it's easier to link to some webpage that tells you to *"never parse ls"* than to read the `ls` manual and see there's a `q` option (and that most implementations default to `q` if the output is to a terminal device which explains why some people here state their `ls` seems to handle filenames with newlines just fine by replacing the newline with a `?` character).